# Error: Objects in this class cannot be edited outside an edit session

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing, error

I'm simply trying to modify the [Default Editing Widget](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/ed_default_editingwidget.html) ESRI sample to show my extent and service and am noticing the following error in Firebug when trying to add a point:

- {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Unable to complete operation.","details":["Unable to perform applyEdits operation."]}}

I also get the following errors in my logs on ArcServer:

- a database error occurred
- objects in this class cannot be edited outside an edit session

Any ideas on why my data is locking like this? Or how I can fix it?

Comment: Is your data in an enterprise geodatabase? Or are you following on these replicated scenarios? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_feature_service/0154000002w8000000/

Comment: yes. the database is registered and the feature service is created and referenced properly in the app